# position respect to all other permutation in probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

i have 6 girls and 8 mens we put them all in one line 
what the probability that the position  numbre 3 in these line have girl in it

i try these but i am not sure

my try :

we have
g = girl

b = boy

b,b,  6 * 11!

g,g , 4 * 11!

g,b , 5 * 11!

b,g , 5 * 11!

that mean all possibility of having a girl in 3 position is 4+6+5+5 = 20 * 11!

asuming that A is haveing in position numbre 3  a girl

so `A = 20*11!`

```
and our simple space E = (8+6)! = 14!

i have divide A/E to get the probability of having a girl in 3 position
```

is that a correct way to do it

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow what you have written...but each person is equally likely to be in any position in the line, so the answer is just $\frac 6{14}$.

Comment: ya @lulu i am sorry i mean about having in  position number 3 a girl

Comment: I think I understood correctly, the answer is $\frac 6{14}$.  List the girls as $G_1,G_2,\cdots, G_6$.  The probability, $P(G_i)$ that the person in position $3$ is $G_i$ is $\frac 1{14}$ by symmetry.  Thus the probability that the person is position $3$ is a girl is $P(G_1)+\cdots +P(G_6)=\frac 6{14}$.

Comment: but u didn't consider all permutation of girl and boy

Comment: I don't need to.  I only care about position $3$, you didn't ask about the rest of them.

Comment: Try it by hand with a smaller collection.  Take, say, $2$ dimes  and $3$ pennies.  List all the arrangements of them.    pick a place in the line and verify that the probability that there is a dime in that position is $\frac 25$.

Comment: ya that same to me true / please can u give a reason why my method is not correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55304/discussion-between-khalid-es-safi-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense out of what you wrote.   If you insist on looking at the first three placements:  $P(GGG)=\frac 6{14}\times \frac 5{13}\times \frac 4{12}$, $P(BBG)=\frac 8{14}\times \frac 7{13}\times \frac 6{12} $. $P(GBG)=P(BGG)=\frac 6{14}\times \frac 8{13}\times \frac 5{12}$ .  Add these up and cofirm that you get $\frac 6{14}=\frac 37$.

Comment: Sorry, again...I don't go into private chat rooms.

Comment: As an alternate derivation:  if we treat the people as indistinguishable, except for gender, then there are $\binom 5{13}$ ways to arrange them so that a girl is in position $3$.  As there are $\binom 6{14}$ ways to arrange them with no constraint, the probability you want is the ratio, again $\frac 6{14}$.

Comment: woooow bro u are awsome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> b,b, 6 * 11!

It looks like you are saying that if you have two boys in the first position, there are six ways to place a girl in third position and 11! ways to arrange the remaining $8+6-3$ people.

You have neglected to count ways to select boys-or-girls into the first two positions. In this case: select from 8 boys could for first, from 7 other boys for second, from 6 girls for third.   And so on for the other cases:

$$\dfrac{(8\cdot 7\cdot 6+8\cdot 6\cdot 5+ 6\cdot 8\cdot 5+6\cdot 5\cdot 4)\cdot 11!}{14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 11!}=\dfrac{6}{8+6}=\dfrac 37$$

Which is, unsurprisingly, the probability for selecting from *six* girls into the third position when any from the *fourteen* boys-and-girls may be selected into there without bias.